# How can I call local method in Linq to Entities query?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have the following code:

```
public void SalesCount(string customerId)
{
  ..
  ..
  return ...;
}

var resultQuery = dataContext.Customers
.Where (c => c.Name == "Alugili")
.Where (c => SalesCount(c.CustomerId) < 100);
```

When I execute resultQuery I get a translation to SQL exception.

I need to call **SalesCount** in the **Where** can I do that is there any workaround for this problem!

Comment: Linq2SQL in header, EF in tags. Where is the truth? :)

Comment: Linq2SQL and EF is similar but exactly different technologies. I think, you are confused somewhere.

Comment: lol sorry :-) I mean linq to entities dynamic query I will correct the header.

Comment: When faced with a situation such as this, you musk ask yourself: Is it possible to implement whatever `SalesCount` is doing in T-SQL ? If so, try to make a VIEW which represents the `Customers` table but adds an extra column (the result of `SalesCount`). Then map that VIEW in your LINQ to SQL entities, and perform selects on that entity. In this manner, you avoid bringing a load of records to be treated in .NET and let the RDBMS do it for you.

Comment: To find the best solution, i think, it is necessary to understand the logic of `SalesCount`.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I hide the SalesCount method with intention forget about it I just need to call any local method from my class in the Where. I do not thing this is possible because I have to load all objects to memory and EF does not support this now.

Comment: Might be worth reading  http://www.scheibler-entwicklung.de/blog/post/Expressables-or-How-to-enable-the-use-of-method-calls-in-Linq-queries-%28Part-3%29.aspx

Comment: @EduardDumitru T-SQL by adding and retriving the data from DB  is a red line when we use we lost the type safty I have just used it in some use cases like database setting changing.

Comment: Extremely, you can make CLR UDF and call it in your linq. In cases, mentioned below, you will get memory load whwn use ToArray, AsEnumerable or so.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan this sound very good and new for me I just check it out in the internet not for this problem but for another problem might be a good soultion! thanks

Comment: @RolandShaw thanks for link I will exactly try to extend my Linq library to this principle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply you can't. You can't execute C# code on the SQL server directly, you can use only `Expressions` and some special recognized functions...

Unless you transform your query (at least partially) in a LINQ-to-Objects...

```
var resultQuery = dataContext.Customers
    .Where (c => c.Name == "Alugili")
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where (c => SalesCount(c.CustomerId) < 100);
```

Be aware that the last `Where` will be executed on the client side, so many useless rows will be fetched from the DB.

Comment: +1 for using `AsEnumerable()` this prevents unneccessary loading in memory when the 'in memory query' is expanded.

Comment: ToList and ToArray loads the data directly but AsEnumerable does not I will test it and give you a feedback thanks a lot!

Comment: In this case the `ToList`, `ToArray` and `AsEnumerable` similar in point of view of memopry loading. Keyword is `materialized query`.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan do you have any link or any useful information about that?

Comment: I think this is the most reasonable soultion for the problem the entities are loaded in the memory EF does not support this function for now I will use this and I can extend the dynamic library when I have time I will post the extenation. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var resultQuery = dataContext.Customers
.Where (c => c.Name == "Alugili")
.ToArray()
.Where (c => SalesCount(c.CustomerId) < 100);
```

But then the second `Where` is not run as SQL but locally - all customers with the name "Alugili" are pulled from the DB...

Otherwise you have to write out your method directly in the where method as lambda expression.

Comment: It is working thanks a lot can you tell me please ToArray will loads all entities from database? I have a lazy loading I do not need to load them all is this possible or not?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://damieng.com/blog/2009/06/24/client-side-properties-and-any-remote-linq-provider. Maybe this solves your problem.

Comment: You must understand that @xanatos made the same thing. It is also working. No, it will load all the entities which survive the `c => c.Name = "Alugili"`.. In a wider scenario, dangerously many records, but possibly not all of them...

Answer (score -1):

Add && between two where condition..It will work

Answer (score -2):

yes, you can.

but you should change return type for your function:

```
public **int** SalesCount(string customerId)
{
  ..
  ..
  return 500;
}


var resultQuery = dataContext.Customers.AsEnumerable()
                 .Where (c => c.Name == "Alugili" && SalesCount(c.CustomerId) < 100);
```

Comment: no, you can't. The RDBMS is the one actually executing the query. In this scenario, the LINQ code is just an orchestrator based on which SQL queries are written, sent to the database and executed there. If it were true, then executing .Count() on a random LINQ query would cause the entire table to be transported into .NET, via the TCP connection, and each row checked for whatever condition the user programmer had in mind, just to compute a Count.

Comment: @EduardDumitru my code is just convert linq2sql   to  linq2Object

Comment: If you pay attention to what the asking user wrote you'll notice the line of code `var resultQuery = dataContext.Customers`. Presuming he's not trying to trick us in any way intentionally, he's more than likely using LINQ to SQL and one could also presume he's doing all of this with SQL Server. It is highly expensive to do what you said. All the where clauses that **can** be performed by the DB should be placed before the call to `.AsEnumerable()`. Furthemore: The answer was **no, no you cant, but you CAN bring everything in .NET, and cause major resource consumption**