# OrderBy a subset of relationship with condtions

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I'm attempting to order `Foo` by `Bars.Max(Date)` on a subset of `Bars` that doesn't have an `Optional`.

It's hard to explain in text so here's the query I got so far.

```
// Foos is of type DbSet<Foo> a "code first" EF entity
Foos.OrderBy(f => f.Bars
                  .Where(b => b.Optional == null)
                  .Max(b => b.Date));
```

That query fails with a `NotSupportedException`

> Cannot compare elements of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1'. Only primitive types,
>   enumeration types and entity types are supported.

**Model**

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; } // one to many
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Optional> Optional { get; set; } // zero to many
}

public class Optional
{
    // omitted for brevity
}
```

Comment: When you say `Foo.OrderBy(f => f.Bars
                  .Where(b => b.Optional == null)
                  .Max(b => b.Date));` what is `Foo` ? Is it a local variable of type `Foo` ? Something like `Foo Foo = new Foo();` ?

Comment: Foo is a DbSet<Foo>, so actually it should be called Foos. Perhaps I should clearly point that out. I thought it would be obvious from the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bar.Optional` is a collection, not a single reference. You cannot compare collections with `null` with LINQ-to-Entities. Instead you must filter by the `Bars` where the `Optional` collection does **not** (`!`) have **Any** element:

```
Foos.OrderBy(f => f.Bars
                   .Where(b => !b.Optional.Any())
                   .Max(b => b.Date));
```

It might be necessary that you must use `Max(b => (DateTime?)b.Date)` instead of just `Max(b => b.Date)` to account for the possible case that the `Bars` collection of a `Foo` might be empty and therefore doesn't have a maximum `Date`. I'm not 100% sure about that. You should test the case of an empty `Bars` collection explicitly.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you. I was polluted by "model first" approach :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  Foo.OrderBy(f => f.Bars
 .Where(b => b.Optional == null).AsEnumerable().
 .Max(b => b.Date));
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not just impressed by the answers you got for the question you posted earlier ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714821/how-can-i-call-local-method-in-linq-to-entities-query

Comment: @EduardDumitru lol , Yes you have right! I did not even read the whole Quesition I Just saw the problem .

Comment: Why this will not work as far as I know that Linq 2 Entities does not support DateTime you have to load them in memory try ToLoist().

Comment: What are you talking about, they do support DateTime and no, you don't have to load them in memory as long as you know what you are doing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146300/linq-to-entityframework-datetime  @Snæbjørn did this link solved your problem? or im in the wrong film?

Comment: His scenario is different from the question you posted.

Comment: @LeoLorenzoLuis go ahead post your answer!

Comment: I did, if you are paying attention.

Comment: @BassamAlugili That solution requires more then one trip to the database. I would like avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Given your Foo is a collection of Foos, Try this

```
Foo.OrderBy(f =>f.Bars.Where(x => x.Optional == null)
                                        .Max(x => x.Date)));
```

Comment: I'm getting a compile error "A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree".

Comment: @BassamAlugili Yes, but I want to try a solution that doesn't use it. As it give me all sorts of problems later.

Comment: What is Foos? Can you query all the Foos and do a ToList()  and do it again. I'm assuming your Foos is a Context from EF.

Comment: @Snæbjørn mark this answer if helping you and you can also use DefaultIEmpty as improvement thanks.

Comment: @LeoLorenzoLuis Yes Foos is from my DbContext. It's of type DbSet<Foo>.

Comment: Can you ToList when you query the DbSet<Foo>

Comment: Yes I can call ToList but I would really like to avoid that as currently I'm passing my query as a IQueryable for paging.

Comment: Ok, try this. ss.OrderBy(f =>f.Bars.Where(x => x.Optional == null)
                                                 .Max(x => x.Date));

Comment: Given, that your navigation properties (Collections) are eager loaded.

Comment: @EduardDumitru Is this not just your answer?

Comment: @LeoLorenzoLuis isn't `ss.OrderBy(f =>f.Bars.Where(x => x.Optional == null) .Max(x => x.Date));` what I posted as the problem query to being with :)?
Anyway I tried eager loading the collections still no luck.

Comment: Oops, let me recreate it with an actual Context not just List<T> :p

Comment: Here, 
            ss.OrderBy(f => f.Bars.Select(x => x.Date).Max());