# Using a custom method in LINQ to Entities

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I have a LINQ expression:

```
        var users = db.Relationships.Where(i => i.RelationshipId== relId)
            .Select(s => s.User).Distinct().Select(s => new UserViewModel() {
            Username = s.Username,
            LastActiveDateTime = s.LastActive, // DateTime, I want it to be a string filtered through my custom GetFriendlyDate method
        }).ToList();

        // convert all DateTimes - yuck!
        foreach (var userViewModel in users) {
            userViewModel.LastActive = DateFriendly.GetFriendlyDate(userViewModel.LastActiveDateTime);
        }
```

This solution is working, but it feels wrong to

- have to iterate over all `users` after getting them from the db, just to reformat a property on every single one
- have a DateTime property on my ViewModel just so that it can later be converted to a string and never touched again

Is there any way I can use the `GetFriendlyDate` method directly within the query?

Comment: And you know what's funny? A lot of people think that they can unit test EF code. They create fake db context with in memory IDbSet and write code like above and it passes the test. Yet on production ... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solutions, worth to mention:

**Have a getter** property of your ViewModel, which would return transformed string, something like:

```
public string LastActive
{
    get
    {
        return DateFriendly.GetFriendlyDate(LastActiveDateTime);        
    }
}
```

Though it not solves your problem with existing LastActiveDateTime column, transformation will be applied only at moment of usage (in your view, most likely - anyways if you will try use it somewhere latter in query, it will not work for reason you already know), so no need to iterate manually.

**Create View**, which will transform data on server side; so your data will already be returned in format you need, if you're using DBFirst, probably, it's easiest and fastest solution;

Finally, you can **use ToList() twice**, once **before** selecting new ViewModel() (or call AsEnumerable(), or find other way to **materialize** query). It will fetch data from database and will allow you perform any C#-side functions you want directly in query after ToList(). But, as mentioned before - it's about getting all data, which matched criteria up to ToList() - in most cases it's not appropriate solution.

And here is some additional readings:

[How can I call local method in Linq to Entities query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714821/how-can-i-call-local-method-in-linq-to-entities-query)

Answer (score 0):

I tested it in LINQpad and it works.
It still kinda iterates over users (with LINQ) but you don't have to add DateTime property to your viewmodel class. Also you could convert collection of Users to collection of UserViewModel objects with Automapper. It would still iterate over users of course but you wouldn't see it.

Had to create some setup code of course because I don't have your database.

```
void Main()
{
        var db = new List<User> { 
            new User { LastActive = DateTime.Now, Username = "Adam", Lastname = "Nowak" },
            new User { LastActive = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1), Username = "Eve", Lastname = "Kowalska"}
        };

        // select only properties that you need from database
        var users = db
            .Select(user => new { Username = user.Username, LastActive = user.LastActive})
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();

        var usersVM = from u in users
        select new UserViewModel { Username = u.Username, LastActiveDateTime = DateFriendly.GetFriendlyDate(u.LastActive)};

        usersVM.Dump();
}

        class User
        {
            public DateTime LastActive;
            public string Username;
            public string Lastname;
        };
        class UserViewModel
        {
            public string Username;
            public string LastActiveDateTime;
        }

        static class DateFriendly
        {
            public static string GetFriendlyDate(DateTime date)        
            {
                return "friendly date " + date.Year;
            }
        }
```

And this outputs

Username LastActiveDateTime

Adam friendly date 2013

Eve friendly date 2014

Comment: It works, since you're dealing with local list of objects. Question is - how to execute this query on EntityCollection. And with this situation you will have troubles...

Comment: But this takes you back to square one.

Comment: What do you mean? You don't add unnecessary property to ViewModel class, so it is better.

Answer (score -1):

There is no direct Concert.ToDate method available for LINQ. But you can try using the DateAdd method from the SqlFunctions class:

```
var users = db.Relationships.Where(i => i.RelationshipId== relId)
    .Select(s => new 
    {
        s.User.Username,
        LastActive=SqlFunctions.DateAdd("d",0, s.LastActive)
    })
    .ToList().Select(s => new UserViewModel()
    {
        Username = s.Username,
        LastActiveDateTime = s.LastActive
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

Wouldn't the following work?

```
var users = db.Relationships.Where(i => i.RelationshipId== relId)
        .Select(s => s.User).Distinct().Select(s => new UserViewModel() {
        Username = s.Username,
        LastActiveDateTime = DateFriendly.GetFriendlyDate(s.LastActive)        
    }).ToList();
```